# need help saving file from onclick function in javascript

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, onclick

i need help saving this, i can swap images but not save them. i am thinking maybe an update button to store the images. or maybe auto save when changes are made. someone mentioned cookies or something. i am not familiar with cookies and would like an easier solution.
actual page will have around 100 images and do need save function for permanently keeping changes.

hoping someone can figure this out, been at this for hours to just get this far
thanks ahead of time for just looking at this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Swap demo</title>

<style type="text/css">
#GALLERY td {
height: 200px; width: 200px;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
}
#GALLERY td img, #GALLERY td img.normal {
border: solid white 5px;
}
#GALLERY td img.highlighted {
border: solid red 5px;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>
  <table id="GALLERY">
  <tr>
      <td>
          <img src="http://www.clearviewarts.com/thumbnails/Puppy In Basket.jpg"      alt="Dogs"/>          
      </td>
      <td>
          <img src="http://www.clearviewarts.com/thumbnails/BabyIndy.jpg" alt="Dogs"/>          
      </td>
      <td>
          <img src="http://www.clearviewarts.com/thumbnails/HarlequinDane.jpg" alt="Dogs"/>          
      </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>
          <img src="http://www.clearviewarts.com/thumbnails/Pug.jpg" alt="Dogs"/>          
      </td>
      <td>
          <img src="http://www.clearviewarts.com/thumbnails/Wagner-edit1.jpg" alt="Dogs"/>          
      </td>
      <td>
          <img src="http://www.clearviewarts.com/thumbnails/CanusAngelicus.jpg" alt="Dogs"/>          
      </td>
  </tr>
  </table>

<script type="text/javascript">
var pix = document.getElementById("GALLERY").getElementsByTagName("img");
for ( var p = 0; p < pix.length; ++p )
{
pix[p].onclick = picclick;
}

var firstImage = null;
function picclick( )
{
// to cancel a swap, click on first image again:
if ( firstImage == this ) 
{
    this.className = "normal";
    firstImage = null;
    return;
}
// is this first image clicked on?
if ( firstImage == null )
{
    // yes
    firstImage = this;
    this.className = "highlighted";
    return; // nothing more to do
}
// aha! second image clicked on, so do swap
firstImage.className = "normal";
var temp = this.src;
this.src = firstImage.src;
firstImage.src = temp;
firstImage = null;

}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to save it so that when the user reloads the page, the changes are still done? I think a JSFiddle of this working would be great so I can see what this is actually doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I would do (I hope this helps).

- Build an array of the image names in JS (on the server).
- Render the HTML according to the array (via JS).
- If the user does an image swap, alter the array, and re-render.

  - The rendering shouldn't need to pull any data from the server so won't flicker.
  - The onclick event should tell the update function which image is being changed.
- If you want to save the display order, POST the current array back to the server.

If that sounds too complex, look at these

- http://inspiretrends.com/free-jquery-carousel-plugins/
- http://webdesigntunes.com/freebies/30-amazing-free-jquery-slider-and-carousel-plugins-of-2013/

Look at http://owenberesford.me.uk/17690427/sample.html 
but pls know that:

- for "real" code, i generally start with a testcase...
- this works on FF and Opera (both Linux), not tested on anything MSIE.
- to allow maximum freedom no framework has been used.
- everything is run on the client, so you can just view/ save.

Comment: yes  that sounds more like what i need,  i am not that familiar with javasript though, wish i can see a sample of at least 2 images i can do the rest